# Python library imapclient idle marking emails as read

Tags: python, imap

*Edit: I have since raised this as an issue on [github](https://github.com/mjs/imapclient/issues/351).*

I am trying to use the idle mode of imapclient library. Using only their given [example](https://github.com/mjs/imapclient/blob/master/examples/idle_example.py) the emails that come in while in idle mode are being marked as read. I first get server response that the message is seen, but then it seems like the library is fetching the email and setting the seen flag. Is this the way it is supposed to be or am I missing something?
here is what the output looks like:

```
Connection is now in IDLE mode, send yourself an email or quit with ^c
('Server sent:', [(330, 'EXISTS')])
('Server sent:', [(330, 'FETCH', ('UID', 484, 'FLAGS', ('\\Seen',)))])
```

Here is the output with debugging turned on.
Seems like it *is* the imapclient making the fetch.

```
('Server sent:', 'nothing')
2018-05-10 21:00:13,325 - DEBUG: < * 328 EXISTS
('Server sent:', [(328, 'EXISTS')])
2018-05-10 21:00:28,342 - DEBUG: < * 328 FETCH (UID 513 FLAGS (\Seen))
('Server sent:', [(328, 'FETCH', ('UID', 513, 'FLAGS', ('\\Seen',)))])
```

Here is the <strike>relevant part of the</strike> [full] code I used:

```
# Open a connection in IDLE mode and wait for notifications from the
# server.

from imapclient import IMAPClient

HOST = 'imap.host.com'
USERNAME = 'someuser'
PASSWORD = 'password'

server = IMAPClient(HOST)
server.login(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
server.select_folder('INBOX')

# Start IDLE mode
server.idle()
print("Connection is now in IDLE mode, send yourself an email or quit with ^c")

while True:
    try:
        # Wait for up to 30 seconds for an IDLE response
        responses = server.idle_check(timeout=30)
        print("Server sent:", responses if responses else "nothing")
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        break

server.idle_done()
print("\nIDLE mode done")
server.logout()
```

Comment: When you fetch are you using the peek variants?

Comment: Looks like you're not fetching: are you sure there's not another email client reading the box separately?

Comment: I am not running anything more than the example code. I do have other email clients but this only happens if this script is running. I will edit the question to include the full (sanitized) code.

Comment: And I will logout of other email clients.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? Actually I am running into the same problems you described.